# UEFI Event Logs

Tags: events, bios, uefi, eventlog-source

I am unable to get the event logs in UEFI mode tried in different ways like from BIOS settings of the Intel NUC board and tried using the UEFI application but failed to collect UEFI event logs
also tried on different platforms like Lenovo Thinkboot advanced setting options but no option was available for collecting event logs

expecting to know how to get UEFI event logs to catch in a file